# matplotlib 2.1.2 figure windows will not close (manually or via keyboard shortcut) after updating to os x High Sierra

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

I am analyzing flow cytometry data using python 2.7.12 with the FlowCytometryTools0.4.5 module.  After updating to High Sierra (macOS), plot-figure windows will no longer close after being called with the show() funtion. Figures are created with pylab 1.13.3 which was installed with matplotlib 2.1.2 alongside FlowCytometryTools 0.4.5 - all modules were installed using the pip install command in the terminal (ex: python2.7 pip install matplotlib). Python still runs in the background after you attempt to close the window, and scripts will continue to run as if the figure has closed, but the window remains on screen, making future work difficult as the window cannot be minimized or removed without force quitting the Launcher (space ship icon).

As mentioned before, FlowCytometryTools uses pylab, so I was interested if plotting through pyplot would yield a different result, but, alas, it was not to be.  Even basic pyplot.plot(s), independent of the FlowCytometry module, had the same problem.  This problem did not exist when running the same script(s) and versions of Python, matplotlib, FlowCytometryTools when running on OS X Sierra.  Interestingly, this problem does not occur when plotting with pyplot using python 3.6 and matplotlib 2.1.2, but, unfortunately FlowCytometryTools runs only on Python 2.
Both pylab and matplotib use the backend 'MacOSX' - at lease that's what appears when I enter the command pylab.rcParams['backend'].

A simple set of code that produces the un-closable figure window is below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = range(10)
y = range(10)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

After entering the show() command the figure appears, but the window cannot be closed without force quitting the Launcher.  Again, I am using Python 2.7.12, matplotlib 2.1.2 and pylab 1.13.3.  This was not a problem using the same code when running OS X Sierra, and is not a problem when the same code above is run with Python 3.6 and matplotlib 2.1.2.

If anyone has any ideas please let me know.

Comment: Could you please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the result? Also, do tell us which version of python and the used modules you use, how you installed them, and what backend you are using. I run High Sierra as well and for me those problems have *gone away* since the update.

Comment: Is there any chance that this question will still be updated?

Comment: On mac these kind of problems have been around for quite some time. I never really found a fix for it, but here is a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44242084/2454357) for the problem. Another option would be to use a different backend, for instance with `plt.switch_backend('TkAgg')`. That backend, however, is rather slow, at least on my machine. Another option would be to indeed use Python 3.6 instead of 2.7 -- is there any strong reason for using the latter?

Comment: The module FlowCytometryTools that I use to unpack FCS (flow cytometry standard) files is currently only supported in python 2.  Thankfully switching to the 'TkAgg' backend solved the problem.  Thank you!

Comment: @aburger FlowCytometryTools should now be python3 compatible