# Manually closing matplotlib plots doesn't release the program

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I call `pyplot.show(block=True)` a window with the correct plot appears. When trying to manually close it, the window closes but the program won't continue to run (like it's still blocked).

For instance, the following program will display the plot window and print `Before`, but after manually closing the window, the program still seems blocked, and `After` is **not** printed.:

```
plt.plot(x,y)
print("Before")
plt.show(block=True)
print("After")
```

I work with the latest *matplotlib* version (2.1.2) using the interactive *TkAgg* backend on *Python 3.5.2*.

**Update** - Additional info: I work with Pycharm 2017.2 on Ubuntu (VM on Windows host)

Comment: weird. works for me with python 3.6 and the latest matplotlib version (actually without block = True)

Comment: Interactive behaviour is imho not so much dependent on the version of matplotlib and Python, but the IDE/interpreter used. Loads of threads about difficulties [with Eclipse/PyDev for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440956/interactive-matplotlib-through-eclipse-pydev).

Comment: The usual behaviour of the code shown is indeed that it prints "After" after you close the plot. If that does not work for you, and you want help with that provide all necessary information about how and where you run this code. Also a screenshot might help. See [mcve].

Comment: Is this on a mac?

Comment: @ThomasKühn I run this on Ubuntu.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I can't see what more information a screenshot  could give. I described the full behavior.

Comment: @Itay Ok, I have experienced this before on mac, this is why I asked. I've never found an actual fix to it, but a workaround, where I would set `block=False` and then hold the program by doing something like `input('press <ENTER> to continue)' so that the program waits for input from the terminal. See for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44242084/2454357).

Comment: At least I can say it works fine with pycharm 2017.1 on windows, see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y44CN.gif).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks, added following your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by unselecting the "Use IPython if available" checkbox in PyCharm's settings.

[image: IPython]